# Where does TexStudio get its citation autocomplete list from?

Tags: texmaker, texstudio

Using `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`, I can reference an external `.bib` file using `\addbibresource{foo.bib}`.

In TeXStudio 2.9.4, autocomplete will provide me with a list of citation keys when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> following `\textcite{`. This is an incredibly useful piece of functionality.

But it clearly caches the autocomplete result somewhere because when I add a new reference to my `.bib` file, the autocomplete list does not include it (although all the older references *are* listed.)

To "force" the reference to appear in the autocomplete list I can manually type the new citation key and compile.
But where does TeXStudio get its autocomplete list from, and why doesn't it expand to include the new reference(s) I've added to the `.bib` file?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe when you execute `biblatex`?

Comment: Seems not to be. You can run `biber` by pressing F11 but that doesn't make the difference.

Comment: Indeed, TXS parses and caches the contents of `.bib` files (everything else would be too slow). You can use `Idefix -> Refresh Structure` to update.

Comment: Thanks @TimHoffmann. While we're on the subject, what the heck *is* Idefix? Sounds like either an Asterix character or fixing problems with the IDE.

Comment: Also @TimHoffmann, [if you post this as an answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments), I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per @TimHoffman's comment, TeXStudio caches the contents of `.bib` files such that updates to the `.bib` might not be reflected in the autocomplete pop-up.

As he also states, doing:

```
Idefix -> Refresh Structure
```

does indeed sort the problem out and new bibliography entries will appear in the autocomplete.