# Create Macro with Reference Auto Complete -- TeXstudio

Tags: macros, citing, texstudio, auto-completion

I frequently use the command `\citeauthor{ME:paper} \cite{ME:paper}`. Further, when one types `\citeauthor{` or `\cite{`, a list of the loaded references appears; I can then type `\cite{ME:p` and hit enter to auto complete. (This happens in TeXstudio at least.) I would like to create a new command

```
\newcommand{\citeauthnum}[1]{\citeauthor{#1} \cite{#1}}
```

But doing this doesn't give me the auto complete options. (I tried `Ctrl+Space` but this doesn't load it.)

Even better, I'd be able to add an optional argument and write `\cite[#2]{#1}`.

---

It looks to me like this question is relevant: [Where does TexStudio get its citation autocomplete list from?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252999/where-does-texstudio-get-its-citation-autocomplete-list-from).

Comment: Any suggestions, anyone? :)

Comment: If you are using `natbib` the command `\citeauthnum` is basically `\citet`, if you use `biblatex` it is `\textcite`, so if you are lucky, you don't have to define a new command at all.

Comment: `\textcite` is perfect, thank you! If you add that as an answer, I'll accept; I'm happy to do it too, but you should get the rep bonus! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `biblatex` with a `numeric` style, then `\textcite` should give you what you wrote `\citeauthnum` for. `\textcite` has the advantage of working properly with pre- and postnote and being able to handle multiple citations. In general I strongly recommend against creating new `\...cite` commands by putting two or more `\...cite` commands together in a `\newcommand`.

With `natbib` `\citet` would be what you are looking for.

Both of these commands are recognised as cite commands by TeXstudio and are auto-completed accordingly.

---

In case you really need to teach TeXstudio about a new `\...cite` command you'll want to add `#c` at the end of the command in the `.cwl` file

```
\citeauthnum{citekey}#c
```

That way TeXstudio will know to auto-complete it with the list of known cite keys.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
\citeauthnum{citekey}
```

to user .cwl file.

If no user .cwl file yet, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361283/190086

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately that hasn't worked. If I type `\citeau` then I see in the *command* autocomplete `\citeauthor{citekey}`, as I did before (except previously `citekey` was replaced with `arg1`, but basically no difference). However, I don't get the reference list autocomplete that I desire (see OP). See picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKK1m.png

Comment: @SamT Did you try `\citeauthnum{citekey}#c` or `\citeauthnum{bibid}#c`? (Cf. https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/blob/master/completion/biblatex.cwl)

Comment: Making that change has fixed it, thank you! As you pointed out above, though, there is actually an in-built