# Get citation autocomplete to work with custom style on TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, biber, auto-completion

I have read through and tried [question 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252999/where-does-texstudio-get-its-citation-autocomplete-list-from) and [question 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357214/texstudio-citation-autocomplete-not-working-with-universal-bib-in-texmf-local), however I still can't get to work.
The autocomplete does not complete, TexStudio can't find the citation. I am using subfile if that matters.

When I include only `\addbibresource` in the main file, instead of my **custom style**, doesn't work, if however I include the `biblatex` package too it works fine.

Compiling results (pdflatex, biber, pdflatex) are fine.

[image: Citation missing]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[stretch=10]{microtype}
%***********************Document*******************

\usepackage{mystyle}

\begin{document}
\cite{Johnson2014}

\chapter{something}
\end{document}
```

And the style:

```
% Declare that this style file requires at least LaTeX version 2e.
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]

% Provide the name of your page, the date it was last updated, and a comment about what it's used for. typography, graphics, maths, sectioning
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}[2022/07/19  custom LaTeX style]

% Now paste your code from the preamble here
%

\setfloatadjustment{figure}{\centering}
\setfloatadjustment{table}{\centering}
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering %esse tbm centraliza

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=abnt-numeric,language=english,alldates=long,sorting=none,hyperref,bibencoding=utf8,citecounter=true,]{biblatex}
%
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{biblatex}{\addbibresource{new_refs.bib}}{\bibliography{literatur}}
\makeatother

%\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1}
\appto{\bibsetup}{\sloppy} %

%
% Finally, we'll use \endinput to indicate that LaTeX can stop reading this file. LaTeX will ignore anything after this line.
\endinput
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autogenerated cwls only check for instances of `\RequirePackage` in .sty files, not `\usepackage`. So change `\usepackage` to `\RequirePackage`, delete the autogenerated `mystyle.cwl` (see file path in section 4.14.5 in the [manual](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/master/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION)), and relaunch TeXstudio. The new autogenerated cwl will contain the line `#include:biblatex`.

For citation autocompletion, you must also have `\addbibresource` in either the main document or in another .tex file that is `\input`. It won't be recognized in a .sty file loaded with `\usepackage` or `\RequirePackage`.

Comment: The new cwl file does include `#include:biblatex` now, but TexStudio still shows `Citation Missing` even after Relaunch+ Idefix refresh structure.

Comment: Sorry, see edit.